# Express.js can't get my CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, express

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

I can't get my CSS files using Express.js but it works using the links.

```
html
  head
    title Welcome
    link(rel='stylesheet' src='/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' src='/css/bootstrap-theme.css')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/bootstrap.js')
  body
    div(class='container')
      input(type='submit' class='btn btn-success')
      h1 Users
      - each name in names
        p= 'Username: ' + name.name
```

Comment: please reformat your code block.It's hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following syntax for including css:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap.css')
```

Just as an html style tag takes an href attribute, so does link within jade.